# Android Manifest error after creating a Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

Everytime i create a flutter application using Android Studio, i always have errors/red lines in the Android Manifest file. Any ideas why this keeps happening?

[image]

Comment: If your app is running fine then thats not a problem

Comment: @JunaidKhalid Its not running fine, when i inspect code and check the errors, one of the errors is 
`Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.pnads.${applicationName}, was not found in the project or the libraries`

Comment: In a Flutter project, Android Studio doesn't read the native Android files properly even when you add Android as a module in the project structure. This leads to the studio showing these errors in the `Manifest.xml` or `build.gradle` files, you can ignore these errors irrespective of what the studio tells you if the app runs in the device. If it doesn't run, then there might be some actual errors. Right now, the `${applicationName}` is correct as I can see.